Match nested route in one of the children in React Router given an id value
Imagine I have the following routes:
const routes = [{
  id: "1",
  path: "animals",
  children: [{
    id: "1.1",
    path: "birds",
    children: [{
      id: "1.1.1",
      path: "colibri",
      element: <Colibri />
    }]
  }]
},
{
  id: "1.2",
  path: "reptiles",
  ...
}]

This is basically a side bar menu, and I would like to click a subitem on that sidebar and be able to navigate to the clicked item. We have the navigateTo hook that takes a path so I need to compute that value. All I have is an id value, like 1.1.1 which I would need to compute a path from that.
How can I use a hook like useMatches or any other lookup method if I am only given a value like 1.1.1 to perform the lookup.
The end goal is that I find entry 1.1.1 with a path of animals/birds/colibri. Yes I could use a DFS approach to compute that path but I am wondering if I can't just leverage some react-router function.
--
To elaborate on my answer, currently I have the following event handler:
const handleItemClick = (item: SidebarItem) => {
  // routes is the RouteObject[] from the example above 
  const route: RouteObject = routeLookupDFS(item.id, routes)
  console.log(route) // {id: "1.1.1", path: "colibri", ...}
  navigate(route.path) // not gonna work because this takes me to /colibri, and not /animals/birds/colibri
}


It's not clear what exactly you are asking for, but I'm going to guess a simple Depth-First-Search is likely what you are looking for. Can you [edit] to provide more details and anything you've tried already?

I don't think React-Router surfaces anything that computes a complete route path based on a RouteObject id property. If you are using this routes definition to form a sidebar menu I don't see any reason why you can't use the path properties to build up the sidebar links. Can you [edit] to include where and how you are trying to use routes to build a sidebar?

@DrewReese thanks once again, added a more concrete case as what I am trying to accomplish

Instead of trying to extract and compute a complete path based on a specific nested route object's id property I suggest building the sidebar menu item link targets recursively, so each level of depth is passed a "path prefix" to append its target segment to.
An example implementation:
Create a recursive "Menu List" component that is passed a path prefix value and the array of children to render. In this example I'm just rendering an unordered list and button elements.
const Menu = ({
  children,
  path = "/"
}: {
  children: RouteObject[];
  path?: string;
}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const currentPath = path.endsWith("/") ? path : `${path}/`;

  const handleItemClick = (item: RouteObject) =>
    navigate(currentPath + item.path);

  return (
    <ul>
      {children.map((child) => {
        const Wrapper = child.element ? "button" : React.Fragment;
        return (
          <li key={child.id}>
            {child.element ? (
              <button type="button" onClick={() => handleItemClick(child)}>
                {child.id} - {child.path} ({currentPath + child.path})
              </button>
            ) : <>{child.id} - {child.path}</>
            }
            {child.children && (
              <Menu path={currentPath + child.path}>{child.children}</Menu>
            )}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

In the Sidebar component pass the routes root as the initial children of the menu list.
const Sidebar = () => (
  <>
    <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    <Menu>{routes}</Menu>
  </>
);



Alternative
If you wanted to go the "path lookup by id" way, then the DFS algorithm should return and append previous results to build up the complete path.
Consider:
const getFullPath = (id: string, routes: RouteObject[]) => {
  const routeLookupDFS = (id: string, routes: RouteObject[]): string[] => {
    for (let child of routes) {
      if (child.id === id) return [child.path];
      if (child.children?.length) {
        const res = routeLookupDFS(id, child.children);
        if (res.length) return [child.path].concat(res);
      }
    }
    return [];
  };

  return routeLookupDFS(id, routes).join("/");
};

Demo:


const Colibri = () => <h1>Colibri</h1>;
const Reptile = () => <h1>Reptile</h1>;

const routes = [
  {
    id: "1",
    path: "animals",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1.1",
        path: "birds",
        children: [
          {
            id: "1.1.1",
            path: "colibri",
            element: <Colibri />
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "1.2",
        path: "reptiles",
        element: <Reptile />
      }
    ]
  }
];

const getFullPath = (id, routes) => {
  const routeLookupDFS = (id, routes) => {
    for (let child of routes) {
      if (child.id === id) return [child.path];
      if (child.children && child.children.length) {
        const res = routeLookupDFS(id, child.children);
        if (res.length) return [child.path].concat(res);
      }
    }
    return [];
  };

  return routeLookupDFS(id, routes).join("/");
};

console.log(getFullPath("1", routes));
console.log(getFullPath("1.1", routes));
console.log(getFullPath("1.1.1", routes));
console.log(getFullPath("1.2", routes));
console.log(getFullPath("2", routes));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



